# Area/Line chart not working as expected with stacking : percent and negative values

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to make a population pyramid type of chart with both bars and lines at the same time.

I also need to place a checkbox to allow the user to switch to percent values.

The problem i'm facing is that the line series are not behaving the same as the bar series when i set `stacking:percent`

The values of the two line series are copied with just a minus in front so i'd expect to see all the values to 50% when switching to percent. But for some reason the blue line is always at 0%.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n3rf054w/1/)

EDIT:

As Bobby Orndorff explained in the comment:

> When stacking line/area series, you add the values of the second series to the values of the first series. If the values of the second series have the same magnitude but different sign then the sum will be zero (i.e. the second series will be plotted at zero). When stacking bar series, positive values are stacked above the zero and negative values are stacked below zero.

So now my question is:

**How do i achieve the same effect as the bar series but using the line/area series? Is it possible without manually editing the dataseries (doing the percentages myself)?**

Comment: Highcharts is working as expected. When stacking line/area series, you add the values of the second series to the values of the first series. If the values of the second series have the same magnitude but different sign then the sum will be zero (i.e. the second series will be plotted at zero). When stacking bar series, positive values are stacked above the zero and negative values are stacked below zero. Visually, it would not make sense to sum the two values the way point/line/area series are stacked. This is the way that most charts handle stacking (e.g. Microsoft Excel charts).

Comment: In the Highcharts stackings are separate for negative and positive values. When we disable your tooltip.formatter you can observe that values are close to 0, because are like -0.4 / -1 etc. so is really close to 0. https://jsfiddle.net/3auzzzwp/

Comment: Sorry @SebastianBochan I didn't fully understand what you said.. The problem is not that my data is close to 0, the problem, like @bobby explained is that stacking for line/area series works differently than bar series. If i put -25 and 25 as values for the first datapoint ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3auzzzwp/1/)) and use the `stacking:percent` option for the line serie it goes to 50% since 25 is 50% of |-25| + |25| then for the other serie since it's -25 the point is placed on the 0 cause it's -50% (50% - 50% = 0).